# Change app name displayed on IOS device with Xcode 14.2

Tags: xcode, react-native

Here is the review of the IOS app on React Native 0.70.1/Xcode 14.2:

```
We noticed that the app name to be displayed on the App Store and the app name displayed on the device do not sufficiently match, which makes it difficult for users to find the app they just downloaded.
```

The name displayed on the device is the subdirectory name when creating React Native with `react-native init myappsubdir`. Now the `myappsubdir` needs to be changed to `app name` for IOS. There are many posts about the name change and they are all not exactly the same and some of solutions seems complicated. To be specific, for IOS (only) on React Native 0.70.1/Xcode 14.2, how to change the app name displayed on IOS device?

Comment: After changing the `product name` under target=> build setting, build and archive run successfully. However uploading to app connect throws error `failed to register bundler identifier`